# image carousel for following requirement using jQuery,javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a slider that allows users to move through reviews by clicking arrows. Which will go from review1 to review2 etc etc. This is what I have so far, I have set up my HTML with my reviews, and my CSS with hidden values for the time being. Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated

```
<div class="review1">
    <h1>&ldquo;THIS PLACE IS AMAZING&rdquo;<br></h1>
     <p class= "vancouver">- The Georgia Straight</p>
    </div>

    <div class="review2">
    <h1>&ldquo;A TASTE OF ITALY IN VANCOUVER&rdquo;<br></h1>
     <p class= "Sun">- The Vancouver Sun</p>
    </div>

    <div class="review3">
    <h1>&ldquo;THIS IS THE REAL DEAL&rdquo;<br></h1>
     <p class= "Yelp">- Yelp.ca</p>
    </div>

    <div class="review4">
    <h1>&ldquo;SIMPLY DELICIOUS&rdquo;<br></h1>
     <p class= "Buzz">- VanCity Buzz</p>
    </div>
and my CSS

.review1{
font-family: Clarendon;
letter-spacing: .2em;
font-size: 22pt;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 200px;
width: 1024px;
}

.review2{
display: none;
font-family: Clarendon;
letter-spacing: .2em;
font-size: 22pt;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 200px;

}

.review3{
display: none;
font-family: Clarendon;
letter-spacing: .2em;
font-size: 22pt;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 200px;

}

.review4{
display: none;
font-family: Clarendon;
letter-spacing: .2em;
font-size: 22pt;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answer

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.review1{
font-family: Clarendon;
letter-spacing: .2em;
font-size: 22pt;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 200px;
width: 1024px;
}

.review2{
display: none;
font-family: Clarendon;
letter-spacing: .2em;
font-size: 22pt;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 200px;

}

.review3{
display: none;
font-family: Clarendon;
letter-spacing: .2em;
font-size: 22pt;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 200px;

}

.review4{
display: none;
font-family: Clarendon;
letter-spacing: .2em;
font-size: 22pt;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 200px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
```

UPDATED FOR PREV,NEXT => http://jsfiddle.net/Su3pG/2/

Paste above HTML as it is in your machine(in New html file)